# backports not working with Python 3.6.3 but is fine with 2.7.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I've imported backports in a Python application. It runs without any issue in `Python 2.7.8` but I get an error with `3.6.3`.

This is the error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'backports')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/venv36/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/venv36/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/cos_config_test/test_config_sdk.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .helpers import skipIfAppVersionIsLowerThan
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/cos_config_test/helpers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from backports import configparser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports'
```

When I run `pip install backports` I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backports (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for backports
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: If you have a SSCCE, you could try asking on the issues tracker: https://github.com/getsentry/responses/issues

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing responses with `pip3` instead of `pip`? Or perhaps `python3 -m pip`?

While some systems are already on python 3, others still require a python 2 environment therefore you just might be installing it under `2.7` instead of `3.6`.